# Previously working code no longer working and giving errors

Tags: errors, thesis

I am writing a thesis using my institution's thesis template. Previously, my working code works just fine. I don't work on that for a few months. When I try to run it again yesterday, I get lots of errors. I use TeXstudio and MikTeX. My working code is as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\let\my@xfloat\@xfloat
\makeatother

\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{UTMThesis, enumerate, amsfonts, longtable, qtree, etoolbox, array, rotating, pgf, tikz, tikz-cd, algorithm, csquotes}

\makeatletter
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{
    \my@xfloat#1[#2]%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \@normalsize \normalsize
}
\makeatother

\allowdisplaybreaks
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix, positioning, shapes, shapes.geometric, calc, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}
\let\openbox\relax
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax

\newcommand*{\qed}{\hfill\ensuremath{\square}}


%-------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{cite}[sort] % change  cite from [1,2,3] to [1-3] etc for number system
\makeatletter                        % change from
  \renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}  % [1] to 1. etc 
\makeatother                         % in list of references
%-----------------------------------------------------------
  \setlength{\voffset}{-2.1cm}
  \setlength{\hoffset}{-.4cm}  
%--------------------------------------------------------
\font\fiverm=cmr5 \input{Pictex.tex} % using pictex
%---------------------------------------------------------
%\pagestyle{plain}
%-------------------------------------------------------
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \lhead{}
  \chead{}
  \rhead{}
  \lfoot{}  
  \cfoot{\vspace{-.35cm}\thepage}  % 
  \rfoot{} 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
  \input{frontmatter/FrontTitle}
  \input{frontmatter/Validation.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/SupervisorDeclaration.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Title.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Declaration.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Dedication.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Acknowledgement.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Abstract.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/Abstrak.tex}
%  \tableofcontents
  \input{frontmatter/TableofContents(Final).tex}  
  %\input{TableofContents(Final1).tex}
  \input{frontmatter/ListofTables(Final).tex} 
  \input{frontmatter/ListofFigures(Final).tex}  
  \input{frontmatter/ListofAbbreviations.tex}
  \input{frontmatter/ListofSymbols.tex}
\mainmatter
  \input{main/Chap1.tex}        %Chapter1
  \input{main/Chap2.tex}        %Chapter2
  \input{DummyChapter.tex}
  \input{main/Chap3.tex}        %Chapter3
  \input{DummyChapter.tex}
  \input{main/Chap4.tex}        %Chapter4
  \input{DummyChapter.tex}
  \input{main/Chap5.tex}    
  \input{main/Chap6.tex}    %Chapter5
  \input{main/Chap7.tex}
  \input{ThesisRefUTMn(Final).tex}%
  \input{DummyChapter.tex}
   \input{main/ListofPublications}
  \input{DummyChapter.tex}
   \input{main/AppendixA.tex}
  \input{DummyChapter.tex}
   \input{main/AppendixB.tex}
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

and the errors that I get is as follows:

[image]

My complete working code can be obtained through this link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rk-SSZDNpN5BIhQtThF08SU0D0z-jnR-/view?usp=sharing

Please, how to solve this?

Comment: please make a more reasonable test file that shows the problem without all the files not needed. As the error is in the title page your test file does not need _any_ of the included chapters so you should be able to make a small self contained example that fits in the question, especially if you can demonstrate it without using local package files

Comment: My guess is: Don't use pictex. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574592/2388

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer for the comment. The problem is solved by using your suggestion.